# Save data from form in database. Key error

Tags: django

models.py:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_big = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

forms.py:

```
class DataForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Data
        exclude = ['is_big']
```

Instead `is_big` from models form I created (in template):

```
<div class="id_is_big-control-group control-group">

            <div class="controls">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" name="is_big" id="id_is_big" /> <span>Is big?</span>
                </label>

         </div>
```

How to save this value in database?

```
form = DataForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    d = form.save(commit=False)
    d.is_big = form.cleaned_data['is_big']
    d.save()
```

return error: **KeyError at /site/ 'is_big'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have excluded the `is_big` from model form. That is why it is not present in the `cleaned_data`. You need to get the value from `POST`:

```
is_big = request.POST.get('is_big')
```

Comment: I created custom input (is it in my question). I excluded is_big

Comment: Why you have excluded it when you needed it in the form?

Comment: Because I do not want to use the generated code from 'models forms'. I added this HTML in my template manualy

Comment: any how you can get the value of `is_big` from `POST` as `request.POST.get('is_big')`